# How to apply css margins on a label

Tags: css, vaadin

I'm trying to put different labels in a CssLayout the problem that label wasn't taken the setted margin. 
Here's what i wrote:

```
 private Component productSettingsLabel = new Label();
  CssLayout layoutRight = new CssLayout() {
       @Override
        protected String getCss(Component c) {
            return "margin-top: 8px; margin-left: 8px";
          }
        }

 layoutRight.addComponent(productSettingsLabel);
 productSettingsLabel.setCaption("Product settings");
```

The specified margins are not applied on the label.

Here's what i get when i inspect the added text with firebug:

```
 <div class="v-caption v-caption-searcher-title">
     <div class="v-captiontext">Product settings</div>
     <div class="v-caption-clearelem"></div>
 </div>
```

A blank horizontal line is displayed under the label here's its inspection result:

```
<div class="v-label v-label-searcher-title 
            searcher-title"  style="margin-top: 8px; margin-left: 8px; width: 434px;">
</div>
```

So the caption is seperated from the label. And since the caption is not considered as a "Component" (in the overrided getCss() method), the style was not applied on it.

I hope i gave all the details.

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: inline-block;` to your style.

```
  private Component productSettingsLabel = new Label();
  CssLayout layoutRight = new CssLayout() {
       @Override
        protected String getCss(Component c) {
            return "display: inline-block; margin-top: 8px; margin-left: 8px";
          }
        }

 layoutRight.addComponent(productSettingsLabel);
 productSettingsLabel.setCaption("Product settings");
```

**Example for** `display: inline-block`:

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  width: 434px;
}
```

```html
<label>Some text</label>
<label>Some text</label>
```

Comment: thank u for help, but i add it and it didn't take the  display: inline-block; i always get  <div class="v-label v-label-searcher-title 
            searcher-title" style="margin-top: 8px; margin-left: 8px; width: 434px;">
</div>